# app-router not working imperatively way

Tags: polymer, web-component

I have this Polymer custom element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/core-animated-pages/core-animated-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/app-router/app-router.html">

<polymer-element name="custom-pages" attributes="selected">
    <template>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom-pages.css">

        <app-router id="router" bindRouter core-animated-pages transitions="cross-fade-all" trailingSlash="ignore">
            <template repeat="{{page in pages}}">
                <app-router path="{{page.path}}" import="{{page.url}}"></app-router>
            </template>
        </app-router>
    </template>
    <script>
        (function() {
            Polymer({
                selected: 0,
                pages: [{
                    path: "/home",
                    url: '../custom-home/custom-home.html'
                }, {
                    path: "/about",
                    url: '../custom-about/custom-about.html'
                }],
                selectedChanged: function(oldValue, newValue) {
                    router = this.$.router;
                    router.go(this.pages[newValue].path);
                }
            });
        })();
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Elements custom-home and custom-about should be lazy loaded when "selected" change, but not is happening (no page is displayed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your `template` definition, nested tags are to be `app-route` rather than `app-routeR`:

```
<app-router id="router" ...>
  <template repeat="{{page in pages}}">
    <!--      ⇓ superfluous r, nested are app-route -->
    <app-router path="{{page.path}}" import="{{page.url}}"></app-router>
    <!-- SHOULD BE: -->
    <app-route path="{{page.path}}" import="{{page.url}}"></app-route>
  </template>
</app-router>
```

Currently you have created a bundle of empty routers.

Plus, the [documentation says](https://github.com/erikringsmuth/app-router#gopath-options):

> If you use `go(path, options)` you should also set the mode to `hash` or `pushstate` on the router.

I am not sure if this affects your case, since you do not seem to pass `options`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, but the error happened when I was editing the question to simplify it. In my code it's there ("]"), so the problems keep active ok? I'll edit, thanks!